# Multi-level Categorical plotting in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, multi-level, valueerror

I am trying to use bokeh to perform some bar chart plotting that will be useful to present data to the user. The Multi-level bar chart categories in the bokeh user guide website look wonderful, and directly match my needs.

However, I wanted to start playing around with the code they provided as examples to see how it worked and what I can change. The problem I am having is that I cannot even run their example code.

The example code they provide to create a multi-level categorical bar chart is:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("bars.html")

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ['2015', '2016', '2017']

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

# this creates [ ("Apples", "2015"), ("Apples", "2016"), ("Apples", "2017"), ("Pears", "2015), ... ]
x = [ (fruit, year) for fruit in fruits for year in years ]
counts = sum(zip(data['2015'], data['2016'], data['2017']), ()) # like an hstack

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, counts=counts))

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*x), plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x='x', top='counts', width=0.9, source=source)

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

However, running this code returns a `ValueError` from the FactorRange class:

```
ValueError: expected an element of either List(String) or List(Int), got [('Apples', '2015'), ('Apples', '2016'), ('Apples', '2017'), ('Pears', '2015'), ('Pears', '2016'), ('Pears', '2017'), ('Nectarines', '2015'), ('Nectarines', '2016'), ('Nectarines', '2017'), ('Plums', '2015'), ('Plums', '2016'), ('Plums', '2017'), ('Grapes', '2015'), ('Grapes', '2016'), ('Grapes', '2017'), ('Strawberries', '2015'), ('Strawberries', '2016'), ('Strawberries', '2017')]
```

Question is: am I missing something? Is there an update I do not have or a module that I need to import in order to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me it works fine with Bokeh 0.12.13. Whats your version?  
import bokeh  
print(bokeh.__version__)

Comment: Hmm. Seems I am running 0.12.5. Likely the issue, will confirm after update. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, did the trick. Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate it. Will definitely check that first in the future.